# Perl variable set from query string not available in subroutine (available in some subroutines!)

Tags: mysql, perl, subroutine

Perl has beaten me down good today and I have a question.  I'm accessing a perl script via a link from another perl script.  agent.pl?agentid=40

In the agent.pl script I'm using the displaying the query string without issues in two different ways:

```
my $thatagent = $q->param('agentid');
$form{agentid}
```

I set the lexical variable at the beginning of my script of outside of all subroutine.  I then use $thatagent to display the agent id number in the "default" subroutine which displays HTML when the script runs.  I don't have any issues here.

```
$dbh->{AutoCommit} = 0;

my $q = CGI->new;

my $thatagent = $q->param('agentid');

my %form = $q->Vars;



if (! $q->param("savebtn")) {
&ViewAgent();
exit;
}

&UpdateAgent();
```

I call two subroutines from the viewagent subroutine and use $form{agentid} in select statements also without issue.

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("select a.name, a.paidcommission, a.paidreferral, paddy.address1, paddy.address2, paddy.city, paddy.state, paddy.zipcode, maddy.address1, maddy.address2, maddy.city, maddy.state, maddy.zipcode, bc.name, bc.phonenumber, bc.phoneext, bc.phonenumber2, bc.phoneext2, bc.fax, bc.email, sc.name, sc.phonenumber, sc.phoneext, sc.phonenumber2, sc.phoneext2, sc.fax, sc.email from agent a inner join entity e on entityid = agentid inner join address paddy on paddy.addressid = physicaladdressid inner join address maddy on maddy.addressid = mailingaddressid inner join contact bc on bc.contactid = billingcontactid inner join contact sc on sc.contactid = salescontactid where a.agentid = $form{agentid};") or die "prepare statement failed: $DBI::errstr\n";
```

and

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("select agentid, note, createdt, createuser from agentnote where agentid = $form{agentid};") or die "prepare statement failed: $DBI::errstr\n";
```

Then comes the problem, I call another subroutine (&updateagent listed above) globally and attempt to use $thatagent but it fails.  If I hard code a number, it works just fine.

```
sub UpdateAgent {


my $sth = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE agent SET name=?, paidcommission=?, paidreferral=?    WHERE agentid=?;") or die "prepare statement failed: $DBI::errstr\n";

$sth->execute($form{'name'}, $form{'paidcommission'}, $form{'paidreferral'}, $thatagent) or die "prepare statement failed: $DBI::errstr\n";

$sth->finish;

}
```

I feel I must have some sort of disconnect with my subroutine "seeing"  the rest of my script but am unsure.  Please help!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is the subroutine defined *after* the declaration of the variable?

Comment: Is mod_perl involved?

Comment: Please reduce the code to the minimum necessary to reproduce the error and post that.

Comment: PS - Your code suffers from SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: It is not no.  I'm not even sure what mod_perl is hehe.

Comment: What can I do to fix the issue of sql injection vulnerabilities?  Do I entirely use placeholders and then place my values to be inserted in my execute statement?  I had been looking into this a little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I added

```
my @thatagent = split(/=/,$ENV{'QUERY_STRING'});

my $thatagent = $thatagent[1];
```

and it kept the variable throughout the script.

I don't know a whole lot about Perl, but man that seems weird.  Like I said, in the initial subroutine displaying the HTML (and the two subroutines called from the HTML subroutine) I was able to use

```
$form{agentid}
```

from where I read my cgi parameters into a hash without issue.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you are running this script under some kind of system such as mod_perl, where the .pl file gets compiled into a subroutine that is called as needed.  The actual code ends up looking like this:

```
sub invoke_agent_pl {
    ...
    my $thatagent = ...;
    ...

    sub updateagent {
        ...
        # do something with $thatagent
        ...
    }
}
```

What happens here is that the $thatagent variable used by updateagent isn't always the same as the $thatagent variable set by the automatically created wrapper invoke_agent_pl.

The easiest fix is to say `our $thatagent`, not `my`.  Better is to not use what are essentially global variables in your script.

Comment: I'm just running it locally with apache, perl and mysql.  I tried using our already :-(

Comment: then: show your apache configuration that tells it how to run .pl files; show a stripped down runnable example that demonstrates the problem.